# Facebook SSO fails after change of email address

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, openid

I changed my Facebook email address, from `first@gmail.com` to `second@gmail.com` (both fictional).

I'm using the Facebook SSO to log in on the SE network. Since I changed my mail address, my Facebook login keeps failing:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

I also have Google accounts for both email addresses, and apparently I can log in using my `first@gmail.com` Google account. If I then attempt to add another login, one that is also registered to my `second@gmail.com` address, I get the same error message as before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had an old network stub registered with the second email address using a Google login. Attempting to login with Facebook with the same email was attempting to merge those two accounts together, but the merge requires approval from the staff because one of your network accounts has a high reputation.

I've merged the two accounts together, and login should work normally for you now.

**Note:** This has nothing to do with changing your email in Facebook. In normal circumstances, it would just work and attach the new email to your account. It's just when you have multiple network accounts that things start getting odd.